# PowerShell 2.0 - Running scripts for the command line call vs. from the ISE

Tags: command-line, powershell, scripting, psake

After writing deployment scripts from within the ISE, we need our [continuous integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) (CI) server to be able to run them automatically, i.e. from the command line or via a batch file.

I have noticed some significant differences between the following calls:

```
powershell.exe -File Script.ps1
powershell.exe -Command "& '.\Script.ps1'"
powershell.exe .\Script.ps1
```

---

Some simple examples:

- When using `-File`, errors are handled in the exact same way as the [ISE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315244.aspx).
- The other two calls seem to ignore the `$ErrorActionPreference` variable, and do not catch `Write-Error` in try/catch blocks.

---

When using [pSake](http://github.com/JamesKovacs/psake):

- The last two calls work perfectly
- Using the ISE or the `-File` parameter will fail with the following error:

`The variable '$script:context' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set`

---

What are the implications of each syntax, and why they are behaving differently? I would ideally like to find a syntax that works all the time **and** behaves like the ISE.

Comment: What do you expect this command will produce? `try { remove-item nonexisting -ea 0 } catch { 'err occured' }` and what if I change -ea to 2? IMHO write-error is not trapped in catch block.

Comment: Thanks for your help stej. Your example worked as I expected, which means the behaviour I mention might be the result of specific calls. I have added a real sample as a separate entry to be more legible than a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an answer, just a note.

I searched for explanation of `-file` parameter. Most sources say only "Execute a script file.". At http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315276.aspx I read

```
Runs the specified script in the local scope ("dot-sourced"), so that the functions
and variables that the script creates are available in the current session. Enter
the script file path and any parameters.
```

After that I tried to call this:

```
powershell -command ". c:\temp\aa\script.ps1"
powershell -file c:\temp\aa\script.ps1
powershell -command "& c:\temp\aa\script.ps1"
```

Note that first two stop after `Get-Foo`, but the last one doesn't.

The problem I describe above is related to modules -- if you define `Get-Foo` inside script.ps1, all the 3 calls I described stop after call to `Get-Foo`.

Just try to define it inside the script.ps1 or dotsource the file with `Get-Foo` and check it. There is a chance it will work :)

Comment: Thanks! You're right, the first two calls seem to do the exact same thing, both regarding error handling and *pSake*.

Regarding modules, workarounds are hard because in a lot of cases the functions belong to internal libraries or third party modules. 

If you have the option though, your suggestion to rename the module to `PS1` and then dot source it worked fine!

I wonder if it's a safer choice to always use `-File` though, so the behaviour is consistent with what you get while developing in the *ISE*.

Comment: As a note, I just found out about this other difference:

When using `powershell.exe .\script.ps1` or `-Command "& script.ps1"`, the **Set-StrictMode** commandlet will not catch any syntax errors in the modules you import.

When using `-File script.ps1` or `-Command ". script.ps1"`, it will catch everything, just like in the ISE.

Comment: Yea, `Set-StrictMode` sets "something", as well as `$errorActionPreference = ..`. It is the same pattern - set something, but it is not used in the module function. Modules are sometimes quite tricky, but in this case I don't know what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a concrete example of the behaviour I described.

*MyModule.psm1*

```
function Get-Foo
{
    Write-Error 'Failed'
}
```

*Script.ps1*

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

$currentFolder = (Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)
Import-Module $currentFolder\MyModule.psm1

try
{
    Get-Foo 
    Write-Host "Success"
}
catch
{
    "Error occurred"
}
```

Running Script.ps1:

- From the ISE, or with the `-File` parameter

  > > will output "Error occurred" and stop
- From the command line without the `-File` parameter

  > > will output "Failed" followed by "Success"  (i.e. not caught)

Comment: It would be better I think to put this in your original Q.