# PowerShell mkdir alias + Set-StrictMode -Version 2. Strange bug. Why?

Tags: powershell, alias, mkdir

It's something unbelievable. This is a PowerShell code snippet in `test.ps1` file:

```
Set-StrictMode -Version 2
mkdir c:\tmp\1  # same with 'md c:\tmp\1'
```

Start `cmd.exe`, navigate to folder with `test.ps1` script and run it:

```
c:\tmp>powershell ".\test.ps1"
```

This produces the following error:

```
The variable '$_' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set.
At line:50 char:38
+         $steppablePipeline.Process($_ <<<< )
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (_:Token) [], ParentContainsEr
   rorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : VariableIsUndefined
```

Why?

It works when started from PowerShell console but not cmd.exe. I discovered this bug in much larger script. It was a WTF moment.

What is wrong with this simple script?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Even though a workaround has already been found, I thought people might be interested in an explanation.

As to why it behaves differently in the shell versus cmd.exe, see [Powershell 2.0 - Running scripts for the command line call vs. from the ISE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894641/powershell-2-0-running-scripts-for-the-command-line-call-vs-from-the-ise)

As mentioned in the reference, there is a difference between the following two commands:

```
powershell ".\test.ps1"
powershell -File ".\test.ps1"
```

When using the first syntax, it seems to mess with scope, causing the Set-StrictMode command to modify the strict mode for functions defined at the global scope.

This triggers a bug (or an incorrect assumption, perhaps) in the definition of the mkdir function.

The function makes use of the GetSteppablePipeline method to proxy the pipeline for the New-Item cmdlet.  However, the author neglected to account for the fact that the PROCESS section is still executed even when there is nothing in the pipeline.  Thus, when the PROCESS section is reached, the $_ automatic variable is not defined.  If strict mode is enabled, an exception will occur.

One way for Microsoft to account for this would be to replace following line:

```
    $steppablePipeline.Process($_)
```

with the following:

```
    if (test-path Variable:Local:_) {
        $steppablePipeline.Process($_)
    }
```

I admit that this may not be the best way to fix it, but the overhead would be negligible.  Another option would be to somehow test if the pipeline is empty in the BEGIN section, and then set $_ to $null.

Either way, if you run your scripts with the "powershell.exe -File filename" syntax, then you won't need to worry about it.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a bug (in PowerShell).

Comment: I used `New-Item 'blah' -type directory` as a workaround. Problem seems to be only with `mkdir` and `md` aliases

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer, but with remark "avoid using aliases in your PowerShell scripts and you'll have no such weird problems".

Comment: But this is not about aliases. `mkdir` is a function and it has an issue when strict mode is on.